# Keep a stationary UITableViewCell while scrolling

Tags: ios5, uitableview

Heres what I would like to do: have one stationary UITableViewCell that can be seen from ANYWHERE in the UITableView. So, when you just have less than 11 entries, it seems like the top cell is just the cell at the 0th index, but if you have more entries in the UITableView, then you can scroll down (usual behavior), but still have the UITableViewCell that was a the 0th index present. Almost like a header row that allows you to see specific items, similar to Excel. In Excel, you can put the top row stationary so when someone scrolls down where you shouldn't be able to see the top row, you still see it.

If more explaining is needed just comment and I'll try to give a better explanation!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your uitableview inside another uiview.
Add a uiview representing your stationary cell as a subview of the uiview.
On tableView didScroll check the cell rect for the first cell (stationary) in the table. 
If it's y is less than 0, it has scrolled out of view and you should show the custom view.
Otherwise hide it.

This way you'll get the same behavior as with the floating table headers. Just to clarify you should have two views for the floating cell. One in the table and one that will "float".