# Keep stationary panel at bottom of visible area of form while scrolling in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scroll, scrollbar

I have a dynamically expanding WinForm that is loading questions from a database, expanding with more questions. I would like to have a panel at the bottom of the visible screen with a save and close button, but the panel stays at the bottom of the form where I have to scroll all the way to the end in order to find them. 
I need to find a way to keep the panel with the buttons at the bottom of the visible area of the form. I was not able to find much information on this, but I tried messing around with some suggestions found here [Draw Border of Panel When it is being Active Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246467/draw-border-of-panel-when-it-is-being-active-scroll/18251370#18251370)
I found someone with a similar problem here [Keep a stationary UITableViewCell while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712906/keep-a-stationary-uitableviewcell-while-scrolling) but that solution does not help me.

Is there a simple solution to move the panel in the form at the same rate as the scrollbar in order to keep it stationary to the user?

Thanks for any help and I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: You linked to an IOS and a WinForms post without specifying what platform you are targeting.  Generally, try separating your scrolling panel from your non-scrolling panel.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes I am using WinForms, I apologize my brains a little scattered after the holidays. The scroll is part of the main form. Are you suggesting a panel as part of the main control and then a separate panel as part of the main control?

Comment: Yes, move the scrolling stuff into a panel that does the scrolling, not the form.

Comment: Put two Panels of the Form: right-click the one that will be positioned at the bottom, select `SendToBack`, right-click the other and pick `BringToFront` this time. Select the bottom one and set `Dock = Bottom` in the PropertyGrid. `Dock = Fill` the other one, also setting `AutoScroll = true` (add the Controls to the auto-scrolling one, of course :) You can also use a TableLayoutPanel, with one Column and two Rows, as the container.

Comment: @Jimi, as a `TableLayoutPanel` can only have one child control per cell, you'd still need to add a `Panel` to the upper cell at least.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, that's exactly what I meant. The description is related to the two Panel guys previously mentioned (the auto-scrolling one and the little brother). The TLP is intended as a layout-aid. Maybe the *relation* didn't come out that strong in the comment.

Comment: Use `TableLayoutPanel` as base control on the form - it will give you resizing capabilities. Then treat each row as you wish